# How do I change my MacBook FaceTime cell phone number?

Tags: macbook-pro, facetime

I have a new cell phone number, and, as my FaceTime on my MacBook still has the old number, and so does my iMessage, I'd like to change it. How can I do it?

Apparently, the only option given, under FaceTime's preferences, is to add another email

Comment: Apple ID account has that information

Answer (score 1):

You can change the phone number associated with your appleid on http://appleid.apple.com

I know that when you update mail addresses there they also update your facetime account, I suppose it should be the same for telephone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Un-check send and receive as that number in Messages and FaceTime and your MacBook will no longer receive or send messages that deliver to that phone number.

Once you've released that number from all devices that connect to your Apple ID, you can clear things from https://appleid.apple.com or if necessary working with Apple Support.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close FaceTime on the iMac.
2. Open Settings/FaceTime on your iPhone.
3. select "iPhone Cellular Calls" on.

You'll be asked to sign in to your Apple id account. Once you have set up this up on your phone then restart FaceTime on iMac, go to preferences and you should see you new number.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to FaceTime preferences and you can choose which email or number and/or add another email or number. iMessage is the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after looking everywhere, I went to my service provider (in Colombia) and the solution was really simple, but not obvious at all.

First, let me explain how the services work here. We have something called “closed plans” and “opened plans”. With the closed plans, you pay a fixed and monthly amount of money for your service, with the opened, you have a monthly fee aswell, but you are allowed to exeed your fee in case your minutes or basic plan is exceeded, opposed to the closed plan.

So, it seems that in order to verify your phone number, Apple charges a little amount of money to your account, like 10 cents or something. So, if your plan is opened, you have no problem, but (like in my case) if your plan is closed, Apple is unable to verify your number.

In my case, I'm able to charge to my plan something like 30 cents and voila! the number was verified and everything was normal again. The costumer service guy told me that everytime I travel to another country and came back again, just have to make sure that I have some money in my plan to Apple be able to verify my number. I know that it sounds weird or something, but after trying everything (even restore my phone and change the SIM card), this was the only solution.

Now, I don't know how things work with your service provider, but in my case, it worked!